# How to link a header and a translation file?

Tags: c++

How does a C++ compiler know in which translation unit or source file it can find the declarations in a header? I mean, the implementations of the various declarations in a header can be in several files, right? So how does the compiler know which one to pick?

And also, when an external variable is used, how does the compiler know which file it is defined in?

Comment: When you say "declaration", do you actually mean "definition"? Otherwise the question makes no sense.

Comment: `how does CPP compiler know which translation unit or source file it could find the definition found in header?` it doesn't. That's the job of the linker.

Comment: It does not matter what files the definitions are in. As long as you compile all of the cpp files with those definitions and then *link* them, everything works. In other words: the compiler does not need to know. Also, the compiler does not pick files. *You* pick files to compile.

Comment: The language is called C++, not CPP. The term "CPP" generally refers to the C preprocessor. - "how does CPP compiler know which translation unit or source file it could find the declarations found in header?" - it doesn't, only the linker knows that. "I mean the implementations of the various declarations in a header can be in several files" - yes, but a declaration doesn't generate actual code, only the definition does.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted and has close request with "author must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved." It's a question how the compiler tool chain works. If the author has the knowledge he wouldn't ask. A minimum example is in this case of no value because no specific problem shall be solved but the understanding shell be improved.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler does not know where the definition is found.

The linker is the tool that looks at compiled objects and links together the object which included the header with the object/library that inculdes the implementation of the function or external variable. The linker takes as imput a list of object files and libraries that it should bring together and also a list of those it should look in.

Answer (score -1):

Due to the terminology of the original question, I misunderstood the question, so this answer doesn't actually answer the question. However, I'll leave it here for future reference about the preprocessor.

---

The preprocessor's `#include` directive can be seen as creating a temporary file which contains the contents of *all* headers included, in the place where the `#include` directive was in the source file.

If you are using GCC you can use the `-E` option when compiling a file, to tell GCC to stop after the preprocessign stage, so you can see this file for yourself.

For the compiler to know which file and source line a specific declaration is on, the preprocessor outputs so called "line" directives. These are special directives (and much similar to preprocessor directives) that the compiler recognizes and uses to set the current filename and line number. See e.g. [this part from the GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Line-Control.html).

Comment: Your statement is true. But does it answer the question? He just wonna know what's the task of the linker and how it works.

Comment: @harper You're correct. I'll add a note about it, but leave it for future reference. :)